# Optimizing "OR" operator to get around SQL Exception "maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000"

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a query using the IN operator, in an array with 1000+ values. I've searched the error so far but couldn't find what I want : **my SELECT is not optimized because I'm using the OR operator and it takes quite a lot of time.**

I'm chopping my query into different arrays at the moment :

```
query = "SELECT\n" +
        "    filename,\n" +
        "    status\n" +
        "FROM\n" +
        "    table1\n" +
        "WHERE\n" +
        "    filename IN " + allFileNames[0];
for(int m=1; m<allFileNames.length; m++) {
        query +=
        " OR\n" +
        "   filename IN " + allFileNames[m];

}
```

What this does is essentially I have the allFileNames array at the moment, and each element of the array contains a string with 1000 file names. I'm using a OR operator on each element of the array.

**How can I optimize all of this ? Is it possible without creating a temporary table ?** Maybe using a substring, but I haven't quite found the solution yet.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I can't use temporary table since I don't have writing access to the database

Comment: Why does your query use 1000+ filenames anyway? Could the process itself be optimized to require fewer elements? Alternatively, you could call the query multiple times and merge the results (e.g. by putting all returned elements into a set or list) - as long as it is `... IN (list)` that should work, `... NOT IN (list)` wouldn't.

Comment: I would load the 1000 filenames into a table (temporary or otherwise), index them, and then join them to the query.

Comment: You ask *How can I optimize all of this?* then dismiss the principal method of optimising the query, whats the objection to temp tables?

Comment: can you show use the content of allFileNames? Also this is wrong: "    filename,\n" if its the only field it will cause an error.

Comment: I've done this sort of thing by loading a temp table; it worked well and was performant, for what it's worth.

Comment: @Thomas I've changed the query in the OP a bit because of professional usages. The number of files can't be reduced because I'm already adding all the files which respect a certain condition in my array. I will try your way of doing it, thanks !

Comment: @Strawberry is it possible to make a temporary table when you don't have writing access to the data base? That's what was worrying me

Comment: @Elanochecer it goes like "m_file_1, m_file_2, m_file_3", etc. Oh yes you're right that's because I've removed some properties from the select to make it easier to read

Comment: Where do those filenames come from? Is it the result of a query? If so, could you combine them, e.g. via a subselect? If they come from somewhere else I hope you have control over what those filenames contain or otherwise adding them directly to the query would make it vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I get these names from an API, that's why I can't use a subquery;
Really is it so ? How can I prevent that, is there any tutorial you recommend ? Thanks

Comment: What version of MySQL?  I think some versions allow `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` even on a readonly server.

Comment: If those are strings, where are the quotes around them?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming single `allFileNames` entry is a single file name, then you can flatten everything under one IN statement.

```
query = "SELECT\n" +
        "    filename,\n" +
        "FROM\n" +
        "    table1\n" +
        "WHERE\n" +
        "    filename IN (" + allFileNames.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","))
        +")"
```

Because all of your conditions, joined by `OR` statements are using same property, you should merge them.

But if your `allFileNames` collections is too large, then you may consider executing your query in batches:

- split your `allFileNames` collection to batches of 100-1000 then execute query for each batch
- aggregate all results

Comment: allFileNames is a string array, with each element being "m_file_1, m_file_2, ..., m_file_1000", then "m_file_1001,...,m_file_2000" etc, thats what i've thought about to make the OR works. But it's not optimal...

So your suggestion is making multiple requests and merging the results, instead of making a request of multiple strings, right ?

Comment: I have seen an `IN` list with 70,000 items in it.  The performance was not great, but it worked.

Comment: @Mich Yes. In order to optimize the time you could use ForkJoinPool from jdk 7. Witch will help divide input and merge output. Or do it paralel.